# How to solve "unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally"

Tags: javascript, docker

Testing on docker locally. Custom Dockerfile.

Goal is to execute nightwatch framework tests within Docker with Chrome headless.

I've tried changing chrome arguments
I've tried change chrome binary paths
I've tried changing chrome versions

I build my dockerfile - docker build -t coi-automation .
I docker run -it -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm coi-automation:latest

Dockerfile

```html
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update 
#RUN apt-get install --only-upgrade bash
#RUN apt-get install --only-upgrade curl
#RUN apt-get install --only-upgrade sed
#RUN apt-get install --only-upgrade git

RUN ln -s /bin/bash /usr/bin/bash && ln -s /bin/sed /usr/bin/sed && ln -s /bin/sh /usr/bin/sh

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre
RUN update-alternatives --config java
RUN update-alternatives --config javac

RUN apt update \
 && apt install -y \
    curl \
    bash \
    git \
    sed \
    gnupg \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    make \
 && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - \
 && apt install -y nodejs \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Chrome for Selenium
 RUN curl https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -o /chrome.deb
 RUN dpkg -i /chrome.deb || apt-get install -yf
 RUN rm /chrome.deb

# Install chromedriver for Selenium
 RUN curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.31/chromedriver_linux64.zip -o /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
 RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

 COPY ./ ./
 RUN npm install 

 EXPOSE 4444
```

nightwatch.json:

```js
{
  "src_folders" : ["./tests"],
  "output_folder" : "./test-results",
  "custom_commands_path" : "./custom_commands",
  "page_objects_path" : "./page",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",
  "live_output" : false,
  "disable_colors": false,
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "./node_modules/geckodriver/bin/geckodriver",
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver"
    }
  },
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions" : {
          "args" : [
            "--window-size=1325x744",
            "--disable-gpu",
            "--headless",
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--ignore-certificate-errors"],
            "binary": "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
        },
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "loggingPrefs": { "browser": "ALL" }
      }
    }
  },
  "globals" : {
    "waitForConditionTimeout": 5000,
    "retryAssertionTimeout": 20000
  }
}
```

Error:

```html
> 
root@0dd3100c6606:/# npm test

> coi-automation@1.0.0 test /
> nightwatch


[Smoketests/Coi Smoke Tests] Test Suite
=======================================
   Response 500 POST /wd/hub/session (1035ms)
   { value:
      { error:
         [ '  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn\'t exist)',
           '  (The process started from chrome location ./node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)',
           '  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)',
           'Command duration or timeout: 194 milliseconds',
           'Build info: version: \'3.8.1\', revision: \'6e95a6684b\', time: \'2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z\'',
           'System info: host: \'0dd3100c6606\', ip: \'172.17.0.2\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'4.9.125-linuxkit\', java.version: \'1.8.0_212\'',
           'Driver info: driver.version: unknown' ],
        message: 'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally' },
     status: 13 }
   Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally"
       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
_________________________________________________

TEST FAILURE: 1 error during execution 0 tests failed, 0 passed. 2.128s
```

Comment: From looking at the error “Devtools active port file doesn’t exist” looks like you are using incompatible browser and driver versions. Follow this http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and make sure you are running the correct versions.

Comment: @AdiOhana Thank you, I had heard of that and I'm not sure how I missed this, but google-chrome was missing entirely. I combed the log once more and found that it was not successfully installing which makes sense about the error. After trouble shooting and trying different methods of installing within dockerfile, I finally got google chrome to install and now my test is executing. Your comment led me in the direction I needed. Many Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please upvote my comment if you think it helped you